# mongod not starting on Max OS X

Tags: mongodb

It's been nearly a year since I last used Mongodb on Mac OS X and I saw it wasn't running. I've tried everything from uninstalling it using Homebrew and re-installing. When I try to start, I get the following:

```
$  mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
Abort trap: 6
```

Any help in debugging is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found my log file in /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
and buried in the data was

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-16T10:07:29.510+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4671205, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier."}
```

So I downgraded to 4.2 and seems to start up